# No DbContext was found in assembly EF 8

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Tengo un proyecto de Azure Functions principal para mi código y un proyecto de Entidades, estoy intentando crear una migración de mi DbContext, pero me está dando el siguiente error:

> No DbContext was found in assembly 'Project.Functions'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

La estructura de proyectos es la siguiente:

```
> Project.Entities
  - Context
      · MyContext.cs
        { MyContext : DbContext }

> Project.Functions
  · Program.cs
  - Functions
      · Functions.cs
      · Timers.cs
```

He probado varias cosas en el Program.cs para que referenciase al DbContext, principalmente cambiando el constructor.

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {

        //Dependencias + Appsettings.json

        s.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(appSettings.StorageConnectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MyContext).Assembly.FullName)));

    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Por otro lado, también he probado a lanzar distintos comandos, revisando tanto en documentación oficial de MS como en distintas respuestas de StackOverflow que no han llegado a funcionar.

Estos son algunos de los intentos.

```
Proyecto: Project.Functions
Comando: dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate 
Respuesta: No DbContext was found in assembly 'Project.Functions'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.
```

```
Proyecto: Project.Functions
Comando: dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project ..\Project.Entities\
Respuesta: Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type '.' The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Project.Entities'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at designs time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

En este enlace no he encontrado nada que me pueda dar alguna pista para solucionarlo.

Y también de esta forma:

```
Proyecto: Project.Functions
Comando: dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
Respuesta: Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type '.' The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'Project.Entities'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at designs time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Para más información, el proyecto fue hecho siguiendo el modelo Database First, en una versión anterior de .NET Core, se migró a .NET Core 8 y se decidió trasladarlo para mantener el modelo de Code First al igual que tenemos en el resto de proyectos, pero no tengo muy claro como configurarlo.

El código de MyContext es el siguiente:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{

    public MyContext(string connectionString) : base(GetOptions(connectionString))
    {
    }

    private static DbContextOptions GetOptions(string connectionString)
    {
        return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connectionString).Options;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        }
    }

    //DbSets region

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       //Mappings + schemas
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras investigar y probar distintas soluciones, he dado con un comentario que decía que hacía falta el constructor por defecto en el Context.

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext {

//Obligatorio definirlo
public DbContext(){

}

//Definimos el resto de la clase.

}
```

De esta manera Entity Framework parece encontrar el patrón correcto y lanzando el siguiente comando crea las migraciones.

```
cd MyProject.Entities
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```